# Symfony 3.0 load config from php file

Tags: symfony

I try to set up a symfony project with the microcontroller trait. But instead of use a config.yml I want to use a config.php file.

```
return [
    'framework' => [
        'secret' => 'secret_'
    ]
];
```

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: It's been awhile but I'm pretty sure that you can just use a php file returning an array and adjust the loader to use it.  But you are not really buying anything by doing so.  Configuration is a fairly complex component in which values from multiple config files end up being merged together.  The final results is a set of cached php files optimized for speed.  So you may as well follow conventions and use yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using microkernel trait, you can use the `configureContainer` method in your front controller (app.php) to load configuration directly from an array, like this:

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    // PHP equivalent of config.yml
    $c->loadFromExtension('framework', array(
        'secret' => 'S0ME_SECRET'
    ));
}
```

[docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/micro-kernel-trait.html#a-single-file-symfony-application)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the container to set the parameters like

```
$container->setParameter('framework.secret', 'secret_');
```

as explained in the [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files)

Comment: Why? If I declare the config in yml, internally it would also be converted into a php array ... I just want to skip this step.